# Apache PHP 5 header() Problem SSL domains

Tags: php, linux, apache2

I wondered if any one has seen this problem before and if you have an answer on how to fix it. Basically I have a pages that are SSL encrypted, and ones that don't/can't be encrypted (due to a plugin dependancy) So on the pages that are none SSL I detect a header and try and redirect to the HTTP version of the page:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
{
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: http://www.example.com");
  exit();
}
```

However PHP seems to block me redirecting from the secure domain to the non secure site of the same domain!

If i go from `https://www.example.com -> http://www.secondsite.com` it works but, `https://www.example.com -> http://www.example.com` forces me to stay on the encrypted site and results in an endless redirect.

Any pointers??

Ric

Comment: not enough reputation to paste more than two links!

Comment: My educated guess is that your Apache set-up is configured to redirect to the secure page. Can you load `http://www.example.com` in your browser if you comment out the PHP redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe make sure your headers have not been sent already which might be the case as keeping on the same page. See this from php manual :

```
function redirect($url, $debug=FALSE){

// If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
// if headers are already sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript is disabled, do html redirect.
} else {

    // Js redirect
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "<!--";
    echo 'window.location.href="'. $url .'";';
    echo "//-->";
    echo '</script>';

    // HTML redirect if js disabled
    echo '<noscript>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
    echo '</noscript>';
}
}//==== End -- Redirect
```